# How to install "PPS Media for ubuntu"?

Tags: installation

I am a Ubuntu newbie from Hong Kong.
I want to install *"PPS Media for Linux Ubuntu"* into my computer.

Firstly, I downloaded a package from http://dl.pps.tv/pps_linux_download.html.
However, when I clicked it to install, the App Center showed me a error.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you add the exact error message that you received to your question?

Comment: Cannot install 'mplayer:i386'

Comment: There is an instruction with pictures : http://briian.com/?p=7390
but that's not work.

Besides, I want to have a friend to tell me something useful in ubuntu if it's possible. Just for share something about ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I know your problem.

PPS is based on **mplayer**. What you should do is just install mplayer first and then install this PPS.

How to install mplayer? Just open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and Copy/Paste code bellow.

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

Comment: "sudo apt-get install mplayer" is a computer instruction?
I don't know how to use it...Sorry.

Or, I can search "mplayer" in the Ubuntu Software Center?
So many results appear. 
Which one is mplayer I need?
"Movie Player for Unix-like System"?

Comment: I have installed "Movie Player for Unix-like System".
but there is the same problem.

Comment: you are running a 64 bit version? I tried , but encounter the same problem as you, and I find that I am on a 64 bit version but the package need a 32bit mplayer

Comment: yeah, it's true that "Movie Player for Unix-like System" is mplayer, and install from software center is perfectly okay,but I guess the problem is that the package is too old and don't support a 64bit computer

Comment: My computer is 64 bit version. There are too many problems with ubuntu, making me feel frustrated. Maybe I will turn it back to Windows 7. (I have 2 hard disks) You can see my other questions in this account.

Comment: Although I can successfully install Kingsoft WPS Office, I can't open it.

Comment: Lol. See my edit above. I simplified things, so, do you understand now? :D

Comment: the thing is like this, you have to use Ubuntu the Ubuntu way, things like ppsstream, which is used a lot in china,but the have bad support for linux, but what you can do is to turn around and find other tools to use.In fact, if you try, you will find that libreoffice much more powerful than WPS, anyway, wish you good luck and enjoy Ubuntu